# How do I initialize an array element which is inside another array element in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

```
$scope.pictures=[
    {
        name:"/images/profile2.jpg",
        caption:"Food and Hunger",
        votes:0,
        User:"xyz@gmail.com",
        comments:[],
        theme:$scope.theme
    },
    {
        name:"/images/profile3.jpg",
        caption:"The wedding day",
        votes:0,
        User:"yamini@gmail.com",
        comments:[],
        theme:$scope.theme
    },
    {
        name:"/images/profile4.jpg",
        caption:"Mother's Care",
        votes:0,
        User:"fakeid@yahoo.com",
        comments:[],
        theme:$scope.theme
}];
```

The "comments:[]" array isnt working. when i try .push() function, it doesnt works. However, when i try push() on other elements like,caption,user etc then it works.

```
$scope.addcomment=function (index) {
    var com=$window.prompt('Please enter your comment');
    $scope.pictures[index].comments.push(com);
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the error?

Comment: _"the error"_? What error?

Comment: what error your are facing , can u just check typeof $scope.pictures[index].comments is an Array?

Comment: do you have any errors displayed at the console when you run the `addcomment`? Try `console.log()` the object to check whether it's as expected.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18822/ its working fine, you need to pass index dynamically or manually

Comment: @SusheelSingh is right, here is my version http://plnkr.co/edit/x5fY2pQRJbrI7R6UZo8F?p=preview, posting just because I made the plunker not that SusheelSingh 's version has something wrong :P

Comment: your version of example is better.@koox00

Answer (score -1):

I have tried what you mentioned in your question, its working fine. see if you have done the same.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18850/)

**html:**

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="pic in pictures">
        {{pic.comments | json }} <button ng-click="addcomment($index)">add comment</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js code:**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$window) {
        $scope.pictures=[
        {
            name:"/images/profile2.jpg",
            caption:"Food and Hunger",
            votes:0,
            User:"xyz@gmail.com",
            comments:[],
            theme:$scope.theme
        },
        {
            name:"/images/profile3.jpg",
            caption:"The wedding day",
            votes:0,
            User:"yamini@gmail.com",
            comments:[],
            theme:$scope.theme
        },
        {
            name:"/images/profile4.jpg",
            caption:"Mother's Care",
            votes:0,
            User:"fakeid@yahoo.com",
            comments:[],
            theme:$scope.theme
        }];
        $scope.addcomment=function (index) {
            var com=$window.prompt('Please enter your comment');
            $scope.pictures[index].comments.push(com);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: please comment my mistake here instead of simply down voting. read the rules